# Perl chmod files exceeding 260 character limit path length

Tags: perl, windows-10, chmod

I have enabled Windows 10 Long Paths following the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later
I did this so I can chmod files exceeding the 260 characters Windows max path length limit in perl.

```
my $ret = chmod(oct(0555), '<path_length_greater_than_260_characters>\somefile.txt');
print "$ret\n";
```

It fails to chmod, `$ret` is `0`.
What are my options?

Comment: Is the path one long filename more than 260 chars? Or can you decompose the path into directories and subdirectories and the base filename? Then you could `chdir` down the path until the remaining path length is less than 260.

Answer (score 2):

There are two versions of each function that accepts/returns a string, an A(NSI) version which accepts/returns a string encoded using the ANSI/Active Code Page, and a W(ide) version which accepts/returns a string a encoded using UTF-16le.

Perl uses the `A` version of functions.

The change you made only applies to some `W` functions.

> These are the directory management functions that no longer have MAX_PATH restrictions if you opt-in to long path behavior: CreateDirectoryW, CreateDirectoryExW GetCurrentDirectoryW RemoveDirectoryW SetCurrentDirectoryW.
>
> These are the file management functions that no longer have MAX_PATH restrictions if you opt-in to long path behavior: CopyFileW, CopyFile2, CopyFileExW, CreateFileW, CreateFile2, CreateHardLinkW, CreateSymbolicLinkW, DeleteFileW, FindFirstFileW, FindFirstFileExW, FindNextFileW, GetFileAttributesW, GetFileAttributesExW, SetFileAttributesW, GetFullPathNameW, GetLongPathNameW, MoveFileW, MoveFileExW, MoveFileWithProgressW, ReplaceFileW, SearchPathW, FindFirstFileNameW, FindNextFileNameW, FindFirstStreamW, FindNextStreamW, GetCompressedFileSizeW, GetFinalPathNameByHandleW.

You can use [Win32::Unicode](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Unicode) to access most of those. You could also access them using [Win32::API](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::API) or [FFI::Platypus](https://metacpan.org/pod/FFI::Platypus).

---

By the way, you can also get around the limit by [prefixing the path with `\\?\`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation) (or replacing `\\` with `\\?\UNC\` for paths already starting with `\\`). For example, something of the form `\\?\d:\dir\file` would be limited to 32,767 characters instead of 260. This works even without enabling the feature mentioned in the OP. That said, this too only works with the `W` functions.

Comment: I forgot to mention the important bit that Perl uses the Perl uses the `A` version of functions.

Comment: I am using strawberry perl v5.32.0. During Win32::Unicode install, I got some test failures. I went ahead running the perl script and I got the message `Can't locate Win32/Unicode.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Win32::Unicode module)`

Comment: @ontherocks You can install that module with `cpan Win32::Unicode`.

Comment: @ontherocks If the only test failures you are getting are for `t/04_print.t`, force the installation of the module (`cpan -f Win32::Unicode`). It's a problem with `printW` [I've already reported](https://github.com/xaicron/p5-win32-unicode/issues/7). It won't get in the way of using the other functions. It won't even get in the way of using `printW` most of the time.

Comment: A few points: (i) I tried `use autodie;` and it says `No such file or directory`. If I delete a few characters from the filename to reduce the path length to less than 260, chmod works. (ii) Prefixing \\?\ did not help. (iii) I am new to perl so I thought there would be a `chmodW` function that would work with `Win32::Unicode` module and that's what you meant in your answer.

Comment: Re "*If I delete a few characters from the filename to reduce the path length to less than 260, chmod works*", Exactly what my answer says would happen. ("That said, this too only works with the W functions." "Perl uses the A version of functions.")

Comment: Re "*I am new to perl so I thought there would be a `chmodW` function*", You can't change unix file system permissions on Windows. You can't even load a unix file system on Windows.

Comment: I am still at wits end what do I exactly need to do? I understand what the `A` and `W` is all about. There is no `chmodW` function that I could just replace `chmod` with, in the OP. Prefixing \\?\ doesn't help in the OP. I am not looking for some elaborate code to replace the one liner in OP.

Comment: Again, `chmod` makes no sense on Windows

Answer (score 0):

[For reasons @ikegami explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65416326/100754), you can use [Win32::LongPath](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::LongPath). From the module's synopsis:

```perl
use File::Spec::Functions;
use Win32::LongPath;
use utf8;
 
# make a really long path w/Unicode from around the world
$path = 'c:';
while (length ($path) < 5000) {
  $path = catdir ($path, 'ελληνικά-русский-日本語-한국-中國的-עִברִית-عربي');
  if (!testL ('e', $path)) {
    mkdirL ($path) or die "unable to create $path ($^E)";
  }
}
print 'ShortPath: ' . shortpathL ($path) . "\n";
 
# next, create a file in the path
$file = catfile ('more interesting characters فارسی-தமிழர்-​ພາສາ​ລາວ');
openL (\$FH, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $file)
  or die ("unable to open $file ($^E)");
print $FH "writing some more Unicode characters\n";
print $FH "דאס שרייבט אַ שורה אין ייִדיש.\n";
close $FH;
 
# now undo everything
unlinkL ($file) or die "unable to delete file ($^E)";
while ($path =~ /[\/\\]/) {
  rmdirL ($path) or die "unable to remove $path ($^E)";
  $path =~ s#[/\\][^/\\]+$##;
}
```

As for `chmod` on Windows, note this caution from [perlport](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlport#chmod):

> (Win32) Only good for changing "owner" read-write access; "group" and "other" bits are meaningless.

For setting Windows specific file access permissions, see [File Security and Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-security-and-access-rights) and [SetNamedSecurityInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-setnamedsecurityinfoa). I haven't used the module, but [Win32::Security::NamedObject](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Security::NamedObject) might be helpful here.